# why load the module at runtime?

Tags: c++, operating-system

Sometimes, I read the source code, found that the module is loaded manually like below.

```
HMODULE hmodMscoree = LoadLibraryEx(L"mscoree.dll", NULL, 0);
typedef HRESULT (STDAPICALLTYPE *GETCORVERSION)(LPWSTR szBuffer, DWORD cchBuffer, DWORD* dwLength);
 GETCORVERSION pfnGETCORVERSION = (GETCORVERSION)GetProcAddress(hmodMscoree, "GetCORVersion");
```

Why does it load the mscoree.dll at runtime?

Best Regards,

Comment: Because they need the `GetCORVersion` function.

Comment: but they are not loading all module they used, only some of them, so I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage is that if you load a DLL *dynamically*, then the presence of a DLL (e.g. mscoree.dll), and the presence of a function in the DLL (e.g. GetCORVersion in mscoree.dll) will be checked *only when the application tries to load the DLL and call the function*, respectively. If the DLL is missing, or one of its function is missing because you only have an older version, then there won't be any problem in cases when the application does not use this functionality. On the contrary, if the DLL is *statically* linked, and it is missing, then the application simply won't start (you will get an error message).

*Example:* we have a complex industrial measurement software, which links [wpcap.dll](http://www.winpcap.org/) dynamically. In cases when the measurement does not include packet sniffing, we do not have to install WinPcap.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for loading a module and using GetProcAddress is that the DLL may not be present on the computer. That way the application can run even if the DLL is not there. You would of course need to verify that both LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress were successful.